# реализация resize в tkinter PhotoImage

Tags: python, tkinter

подскажите как правильно реализовать функцию resize в tkinter PhotoImage? 
функция `__init__` не выводит на экран изображение.

псевдокод:

```
class Image(PhotoImage):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        return super(Image, self).__init__(file)

    def resize(self, xo, yo):
        self.zoom(xo, yo)
        xi, yi = self.getsize(self.file)
        self.subsample(xi, yi)

    def getsize(self):
        ...
        return xi, yi
```

Answer (score 1):

Результат: 
(самостоятельно читает текущие размеры изображения и преобразовывает в заданные размеры)

```
class Image(PhotoImage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file = kwargs['file']
        return super(Image, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def resize(self, xo, yo):
        xi, yi = self.getsize()
        img = self.zoom(xo, yo)
        img = img.subsample(xi, yi)
        return img

    def zoom(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Image, self).zoom(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def subsample(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Image, self).subsample(*args, **kwargs)

    def getsize(self):
        with open(self.file, 'rb') as fhandle:
            head = fhandle.read(24)
            if len(head) != 24:
                return
            if imghdr.what(self.file) == 'png':
                check = struct.unpack('>i', head[4:8])[0]
                if check != 0x0d0a1a0a:
                    return
                x, y = struct.unpack('>ii', head[16:24])
            elif imghdr.what(self.file) == 'gif':
                x, y = struct.unpack('<HH', head[6:10])
            elif imghdr.what(self.file) == 'jpeg':
                try:
                    fhandle.seek(0)
                    size = 2
                    ftype = 0
                    while not 0xc0 <= ftype <= 0xcf:
                        fhandle.seek(size, 1)
                        byte = fhandle.read(1)
                        while ord(byte) == 0xff:
                            byte = fhandle.read(1)
                        ftype = ord(byte)
                        size = struct.unpack('>H', fhandle.read(2))[0] - 2
                    fhandle.seek(1, 1)
                    x, y = struct.unpack('>HH', fhandle.read(4))
                except Exception:
                    return
            else:
                return
            return x, y
```

Вызов:

```
img = Image(file='file.png')
img = img.resize(30, 18)
```

Comment: Класс! Очень круто!

Comment: А вообще `JPEG` `tkinter`-ом не поддерживается!

Answer (score 0):

Зато есть поддержка всех форматов:

```
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

class Image:
    def __init__(self, file = ''):
        self.img = PIL.Image.open(file)
        self.TkImage = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
    def resize(self, size):
        self.img = self.img.resize(size)
        self.TkImage = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
root = tk.Tk()
imga = Image('images/img.tiff')
imga.resize(200, 100)
tk.Label(root, image=imga.TkImage).pack()
root.mainloop()
```